# Subprocess - Grep Broken Pipe

Tags: python, grep, subprocess

Python 2.4.x here.

Been banging my head trying to get subprocess to work with glob.

Well, here's the problem area.

```
def runCommands(thecust, thedevice):
    thepath='/smithy/%s/%s' % (thecust,thedevice)
    thefiles=glob.glob(thepath + '/*.smithy.xml')
    p1=subprocess.Popen(["grep", "<record>"] + thefiles, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p2=subprocess.Popen(['wc -l'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p1.stdout.close()
    thecount=p2.communicate()[0]
    p1.wait()
```

I receive numerous "grep: writing output: Broken pipe" errors on the screen.

It's got to be something simple I'm missing, I just can't spot it.  Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are a couple (very nice) wrappers around subprocess tha will make your life a lot easier like [pbs](https://github.com/amoffat/pbs) and [plumbum](https://github.com/tomerfiliba/plumbum).

Comment: those look really cool - unfortunately i'm not in an environment where I can add modules outside of 2.4's modules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that for `p2` your argument list should be `['wc', '-l']` instead of `['wc -l']`.

Currently it is looking for an executable named `'wc -l'` to run and not finding it, so `p2` immediately fails and there is nothing connected to `p1.stdout`, which results in the broken pipe errors.

Try the following code:

```
def runCommands(thecust, thedevice):
    thepath='/smithy/%s/%s' % (thecust,thedevice)
    thefiles=glob.glob(thepath + '/*.smithy.xml')
    p1=subprocess.Popen(["grep", "<record>"] + thefiles, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p2=subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p1.stdout.close()
    thecount=p2.communicate()[0]
    p1.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because you are closing `p1.stdout` before grep is done outputting. Maybe you meant to close `pt.stdin`? There doesn't seem to be any reason to close either of those though, so I would just remove the `p1.stdout.close()` statement.

Comment: Take a look at the docs:  http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline -- It appears to be done correctly to me.